# beginning: sql server 2008 express with mdf file

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express, mdf

i want to practice connecting from asp.net to a sql server database. i have it in mdf file.

please help me. what is the next step?

i got the sample mdf database from here:

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/37109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- [Install SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)
- [Attach the MDF file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can attach your MDF file to your SQL/Express Server

[How to: Attach a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx)